# How to start 'mongos' route server (MongoDB 2.1.1) on Raspbian?

Tags: mongodb, sharding, nosql

So i used **[THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYzYp1bPCPg)** Tutorial from Eugene Ch'ng for setting up a **MongoDB Shard-Cluster**. Following all his steps works perfect.

My cluster contains **4 raspberry-pi (b+) and my MacBook**.

After setting up my Config-Server (only one for now, due to hardware shortage), i came to the point where i should start the "**mongos**" instance. But there is none.

**/opt/mongo/bin** contains:

```
pi@pi01 /opt/mongo/bin $ ls -l
total 48536
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4986476 May 28 20:16 bsondump
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Jun  1 08:24 cfg0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2376 May 29 10:34 log.cfg0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2734964 May 28 20:28 mongo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6942152 May 28 20:28 mongod
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5006660 May 28 20:32 mongodump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4990416 May 28 20:36 mongoexport
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5018040 May 28 20:39 mongofiles
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5007712 May 28 20:43 mongoimport
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4977940 May 28 20:47 mongooplog
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4990044 May 28 20:50 mongoperf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5013980 May 28 20:54 mongorestore
```

Even this wasn't helping me:

```
sudo find / -name 'mongos'
```

---

**Where can i find the 'mongos' process to start the mongodb route-server?**

Thank you for your help in advance.